# How to add graphical signatures to Entourage 2008 for Mac

Tags: mac, entourage, microsoft-office-2008

I was wondering if its possible to create graphical signatures ( as opposed to plain signatures) on Entourage 2008? And please no Entourage sucks replies ( i have to use this for work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Nope. Entourage does not permit images in the signature.

That's why I love Snow Leopard Mail.app as the alternative to Entourage.

I have to support many users who have not or cannot upgrade to Snow Leopard and this is one of the known drawbacks to Entourage for the last 8-9 years.  Microsoft has identified that customers are so displeased with the Entourage program, that they are rebranding the application "Outlook" in the Office 2010 suite.  However, the Mac Business Unit in MS has already pointed out that it's merely the next version of Entourage and is undergoing something of a Vista/7 style rebranding.

Entourage Web-services Edition brings Entourage 2008 (aka 12.x) up to the planned Office 2010 network scheme (Web-services) and similarly updates the internal application version number to the expected 13.x.  As a point of comparison, Apple uses Exchange Web-services for both the iPhone and Snow Leopard's Exchange support.  EWS is available from [Microsoft's Mac portal](http://www.mactopia.com).

However, none of that discussion matters as the issue in the question is one of User Interface and Functionality.  Also note that Microsoft does not use Apple's built in certificate handler/warning and so if your organization hasn't quite got their SSL cert installed right, every user sees the "The host is not recognized!" warning once per application launch.

Comment: Thanks kinda figured, but have to use this for work

Comment: Ditto, that's why I'm Sooooooo happy Apple licensed Exchange 2007 web services.